# Error with insert value in SQLite3 with python 2.7 script

Tags: python, sql, json

I made a script to insert values taken from a json into a database.
The script works but if it encounters an EMPTY value (example: "") then it returns error without inserting anything. How can I avoid this error?

Here is the script

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(PATH_DB)
cursor = connection.cursor()
table='''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trieste(
   id          INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY
  ,farmaciaId  INTEGER  
  ,codOpenData INTEGER  
  ,ragSoc      VARCHAR(40) 
  ,distanza    NUMBER(10,0) 
  ,indirizzo   VARCHAR(48) 
  ,latitudine  NUMERIC(9,6) 
  ,longitudine NUMERIC(9,6) 
  ,telefono    VARCHAR(11) 
  ,paese       VARCHAR(6) 
  ,provincia   VARCHAR(2) 
  ,localita    VARCHAR(22) 
  ,cap         INTEGER  
  ,stato       VARCHAR(1) 
  ,data        DATE  
  ,oraInizio   VARCHAR(8) 
  ,oraFine     VARCHAR(8)
);'''
cursor.execute(table)

traffic = json.load(open('/var/www/html/src/trieste.json'))
columns = ['farmaciaId','codOpenData','ragSoc','distanza','indirizzo','latitudine','longitudine','telefono','paese','provincia','localita','cap','stato','data','oraInizio','oraFine']
for row in traffic:
    keys= tuple(row[c] for c in columns)
    cursor.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO trieste(farmaciaId,codOpenData,ragSoc,distanza,indirizzo,latitudine,longitudine,telefono,paese,provincia,localita,cap,stato,data,oraInizio,oraFine) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',keys)
```

Thanks

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "riempidatabase.py", line 32, in <module>
    keys= tuple(row[c] for c in columns)
  File "riempidatabase.py", line 32, in <genexpr>
    keys= tuple(row[c] for c in columns)
KeyError: 'oraInizio'
```

json oraInizio and oraFine are MISSING in some cases

```
 {
      "farmaciaId": 558,
      "codOpenData": 5496,
      "ragSoc": "AL CENTAURO",
      "distanza": 0,
      "indirizzo": "Via Domenico Rossetti, 33",
      "latitudine": 45.649959,
      "longitudine": 13.78522,
      "telefono": "040 633080",
      "paese": "Italia",
      "provincia": "1",
      "localita": "Trieste",
      "cap": 34139,
      "stato": "C",
      "data": "2023-03-11"
   },
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please post the full traceback.

Comment: The problem is with `keys= tuple(row[c] for c in columns)` not the SQL statement. Please post a working example of your code.

Comment: Yes, but it only happens with empty fields. Now I put it

Comment: But we need to see what the variable clumns contain and what row is in order to fully understand what is going on.

Comment: Can you give an example of the contents of `trieste.json`

Comment: I'm also fine with skipping lines with empty values

Comment: Yes that would probably fix the issue.

Comment: Or missing field. How do you do?

Comment: It depends on how the json looks like, I cannot help without knowing how the `trieste.json` looks like.

Comment: Looking back at the json I realized that they are really missing... So how can I make it skip that value?